# Extend time range to shutdown command

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-command-prompt

Is it possible to extend the valid range to the DOS shutdown command in Windows Server 2003? The help shows a maximum time-out period at 600 seconds.

Comment: A workaround might be to set a scheduled task but it is not comfortable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. However, as an alternative, you could create a scheduled task to run `shutdown.exe` x number of seconds from the current time, using a powershell script. Or, better yet, use powershell's `set-sleep` in a script to delay executing `shutdown.exe` until You're ready.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the at command to push it off to a later time:

```
at 9:30 shutdown -t 30 -f -s
```